# SQL Group with Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

This feels like it should have a basic solution but I don't seem to be getting it.

Take this query:

```
            SELECT Category FROM Article
            GROUP BY Category
```

I want to effectively do this:

```
            SELECT Category, DatePublished FROM Article 
            GROUP BY Category
            ORDER BY DatePublished DESC
```

I don't really want to select DatePublished, but it seemed to make sense to order by it. That doesn't work though.

Basically I want to order categories by the most recent DatePublished article.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT  Category
FROM    Article
GROUP BY
        Category
ORDER BY
        MAX(DatePublished) DESC
```

Since you do a `GROUP BY`, you need to run some aggregate function over non-grouping columns.

`MAX` will select the date of last published article from each category and order categories accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

In aggregations (--> `GROUP BY`), you can only select/use fields in combination with aggregation functions (e.g. `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`) and fields listed in the `GROUP BY`-clause.

Simple sample:

```
A    |   B
-----+-----
1    |   2
1    |   3
```

if you'd write `SELECT A,B FROM table GROUP BY A`, that would yield:

```
A    |   B
-----+-----
1    |{2,3}
```

but that is not possible (`B` has 2 values in one row!?!). You have to do something with the values of `B` which groups them together, too. So two possibilities:

**1**: Add `B` in the `GROUP BY`-clause

```
SELECT A,B FROM table GROUP BY A,B
```

yields

```
A    |   B
-----+-----
1    |   2
1    |   3
```

**2**: Use an aggregation function on `B`

```
SELECT A,MAX(B) FROM TABLE GROUP BY A,B
```

gives you

```
A    |   B
-----+-----
1    |   3
```

The same arguments apply to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Most of the times when you want to write a statement like the first one I showed up with, possibility 1 is the solution, since you may know that `A` and `B` belong together (common sample: `UserId` and `UserName`) but the RDBMS does not know it!