# How to Group By and Order By - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, sql-server-2016

I need to group by an `UniqueIdentifier` column and then sort the group by a `DateTime` Column, the table also contains the XML column.

Table schema: **StudentMark**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentMark]
(
    [StudentMarkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ScoreInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [GeneratedOn] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentMark] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentMarkId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample seed data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StudentMark] ([StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], GeneratedOn])
VALUES ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15'),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15'),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20'),
       ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20');
```

**Requirement**: I need to group by `[dbo].[StudentMark].[StudentId]` and Sort the Column `[dbo].[StudentMark].[GeneratedOn]` within a group.

I tried the following SQL query but it is causing an error

```
SELECT 
    MAX([StudentMarkId]), [StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], [GeneratedOn]
FROM 
    [dbo].[StudentMark] 
GROUP BY 
    [StudentId]
ORDER BY 
    [GeneratedOn] DESC
```

**Error**:

> Column 'dbo.StudentMark.SubjectId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**Expected Result Set**:

```
3, '0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20'

2, '0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15'

4, 'FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20'

1, 'FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15'
```

I refereed the following question but I can't fix it: [SQL Group with Order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708694/sql-group-with-order-by)

For your kind information I'm using `SQL Server 2016`.

Kindly assist me.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to a set function. In this case [StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], [GeneratedOn].

Comment: @jarlh - I'm getting the following error `The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.`

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and sample results.  A `GROUP BY` query produces one row per group.  There is no sorting "within" a group.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sample seed data already I given, kindly wait 2 more minutes I will update the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX([StudentMarkId]), 
    [StudentId], 
    [SubjectId], 
    convert(varchar(max),[ScoreInfo]) as [ScoreInfo] , [GeneratedOn]
FROM [dbo].[StudentMark] 
GROUP BY [StudentId], [SubjectId], convert(varchar(max), [ScoreInfo]), [GeneratedOn]
ORDER BY [GeneratedOn] DESC
```

Check this also

```
SELECT MAX([StudentMarkId]) 
        over (partition by [StudentId] order by [GeneratedOn] desc) as maxStudentMarkId, 
    [StudentId],
    [SubjectId],
    convert(varchar(max),[ScoreInfo]) as [ScoreInfo] , [GeneratedOn]
FROM [dbo].[StudentMark]
```

Output -

```
maxStudentMarkId    StudentId   SubjectId   ScoreInfo   GeneratedOn
4   FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581    AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB    <StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  2017-08-16 09:06:20.00
4   FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581    0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081    <StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  2017-08-10 10:10:15.00
3   0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2    AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB    <StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  2017-08-16 09:06:20.00
3   0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2    0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081    <StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  2017-08-10 10:10:15.00
```

Comment: Kindly check the resultant record for your query, its returning the recordset in the order `4, 3 , 2, 1` or `[StudentMarkId]`

Comment: it is due to ORDER BY [GeneratedOn] DESC. can you share expected output?

Comment: The second query is working, my question is we can't achieve this by using `Group By` ?

Comment: you want to use aggregate function on only one column so partition by gives better solution that is depending on your requirements.For more information check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404565/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by